# How to get red round minus icon as png with transparent background?

Tags: ios, icons, badge, human-interface

I need the red-minus badge icon - that one which is used for deleting rows in a `UITableView`.
Is there a way to get it programmatically? I have searched via google, browsed in several icon databases - without success.

(to get the icon when I enter the editing-modus of a table is clear - I need the icon as a design element in retina resolution).

Comment: You can get it in this .psd: http://www.teehanlax.com/downloads/ios-5-gui-psd-iphone-4s/

Comment: Why cant you try to take a screenshot of the minus icon in retina screen and also in standard screen??Go ahead.. Its easy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [UIKit-Artwork-Extractor](https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor) for exactly that.